# How multiarray.correlate2(a, v, mode) is actually implemented?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

On my way to understand how the `Numpy.correlate()` function actually works, I get to it's implementation in pure Python, but what I saw was very disappointing:

```
def correlate(a, v, mode='valid', old_behavior=False):
    mode = _mode_from_name(mode)
    if old_behavior:
        warnings.warn("""Warning.""", DeprecationWarning)
        return multiarray.correlate(a, v, mode)
    else:
        return multiarray.correlate2(a, v, mode)
```

So I started to look for implementation of the `multiarray.correlate2(a, v, mode)` function, but unfortunately I can't find it. I'll just say, that I'm looking for it, because I try to implement the autocorrelation function by myself, and I'm missing the functionality similar to `mode='full'` parameter in `Numpy.correlate()` that makes function to return result as a 1D array. Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The speed of python code can be very poor compared to other languages like c. `numpy` aims to provide highly performant operations on arrays, therefore the developers decided to implement some operations in `c`.

Unfortunately, won't find a python implementation of `correlate` in `numpy`'s code base, but if you are familiar with `C` and `python`'s extension modules, you can have find the relevant code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/710be5b4c61aded0d92a057bf488d71af86869f1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1147-1255).

The different modes just specify the length of the output array.
You can simulate them by transforming your inputs:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3]
v = [0, 1, 0.5]
np.correlate(a, v, mode="full")
```

returns:

```
array([ 0.5,  2. ,  3.5,  3. ,  0. ])
```

You can get the same result by filling `v` with zeros:

```
np.correlate(a, [0, 0] + v + [0, 0])
```

returns the same result:

```
array([ 0.5,  2. ,  3.5,  3. ,  0. ])
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you, in addition, explain how this `correlate2()` function works so it gives for `mode='full'` an array?

Comment: @bluevoxel, do you understand how `mode=valid` works? The other two modes just specify how long the output array is. You can calculate the `cross-correlation` for an arbitrary array sizes. Whenever the formula tries to access an invalid index (e.g. `v[-1]`) you just assume that at this position you found a `0`. You get the same result by filling `v` with zeros from the right and the left, until `len(v') == len(a) + len(v) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.core.multiarray.correlate2
dir(np.core.multiarray.correlate2) # to inspect
print (numpy.__version__) 
print numpy.__version__ # python 2
```

found it! it might be a private API, can't find the docs after first search with numpy.multiarray or with the newly discovered  'correct' name.
optimal search query is 'np.core.multiarray.correlate2 github'

```
return multiarray.correlate2(a, v, mode) # mode is int data type
```

if you're plan to customize the code for your purposes, be careful.

```
/*
 * simulates a C-style 1-3 dimensional array which can be accessed using
 * ptr[i]  or ptr[i][j] or ptr[i][j][k] -- requires pointer allocation
 * for 2-d and 3-d.
 *
 * For 2-d and up, ptr is NOT equivalent to a statically defined
 * 2-d or 3-d array.  In particular, it cannot be passed into a
 * function that requires a true pointer to a fixed-size array.
 */

/*NUMPY_API
 * Simulate a C-array
 * steals a reference to typedescr -- can be NULL
 */
NPY_NO_EXPORT int
PyArray_AsCArray(PyObject **op, void *ptr, npy_intp *dims, int nd,
                 PyArray_Descr* type
# NPY_NO_EXPORT int NPY_NUMUSERTYPES = 0;

# omit code
    switch(mode) {
    case 0:
        length = length - n + 1;
        n_left = n_right = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        n_left = (npy_intp)(n/2);
        n_right = n - n_left - 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        n_right = n - 1;
        n_left = n - 1;
        length = length + n - 1;
        break;
    default:
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "mode must be 0, 1, or 2");
        return NULL;
    }
```

don't mess with the internal APIs if this is your first crack at the codebase and you are on a deadline. Too late for me.